# Why Glav Web Cache does not have the data I saved when called from other instance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, caching

I've tried searching for my problems but nothing seems to ask what I wanted to ask.

I'm working on a web service that generates and sends a kind of token from server to client, currently I'm using Glav CacheAdapter (the web cache kind)

When someone requested a data call, the server should generate a token then saves it to a cache, then sends the key to the client, the client then should send the same token to the server and it should be checked with the one in the cache, but somehow when the server generates the key it successfully creates and saves one (I tested when debugging), but when the client call sends the token (it is the same one) but somehow the cache does not contain any data.

[image: Overview of the project]

```
>>>> Project A
>> Service 
public string Generate()
{
    AppServices.Cache.InnerCache.Add($"AuthenticationTokenCache:{xxx}", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), new StringValue() { Value = xxx });
    return key;
}

public bool Validate(string token)
{
    return AppServices.Cache.InnerCache.Get<StringValue>($"AuthenticationTokenCache:{xxx}")  != null;
}

>> WebAPI
public bool CallValidate(string token)
{
    var xService = new Service();
    return xService.Validate(token);
}


>>>> Project B 
>> WebAPI
protected override bool RequestValidation(string token)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var authURL = $"/api/CallValidate?token={token}";
    var response = client.GetAsync(authURL).Result.Content;
    string jsonContent = response.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var authResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bool>(jsonContent);
    if(authResult)
    {
       return true; 
    }    
}
```

Is the cache type I use wrong, or maybe there's something wrong that I don't realize is wrong? 
And when I create new instance of the same class does the cache gets shared between those object or not?

I'm not really sure as to how the details of how caching works, any pointer as to reference reading material would be helpful too.

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glav.CacheAdapter/ is what you are using?

Comment: @mjwills yes that one

Comment: Do you have multiple servers serving the web requests of generating and validating the token? If you are using WebCache, then it is clear that the token stored on cache of one server won't be available if the validate request goes to the other server. The solution for this is to use some common cache store such a memached, redis etc.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That's what I'm afraid too, but from what I understand, the generate and validate function should be in one server, albeit when validating the web service object created one new instance of the class that has the generate and validate function.

Comment: The instance of the object does have little impact here. For things to work fine you need to get the token value back from the Cache. So unless you fix the token store issue, you are kind of stuck.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya When debugging I tried checking the cache before running the second test, using the previous key and when I call the cache during the generate function call, the value is actually stored there, it's just that during validation somehow it does not detect the cache.